# Split a DNA sequence into a list of codons with D

Tags: d

DNA strings consist of an alphabet  of four characters, `A,C,G, and T`
Given a string,

```
ATGTTTAAA
```

I would like to split it in to its constituent codons

```
ATG  TTT AAA  

   codons = ["ATG","TTT","AAA"]
```

codons encode proteins and they are redundant (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNA_codon_table)

I have a DNA string in D and would like to split it into a range 
of codons and later translate/map the codons to amino acids.

std.algorithm has a splitter function which requires a delimiter and also the 
std.regex Splitter function requires a regex to split the string. 
Is there an idiomatic approach to splitting a string without a delimiter?

Comment: You mean, you want to insert a separator character `' '` after every 3 characters?

Comment: I want to get a Range of codons i.e. 3 characters each.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for `chunks`:

```
import std.range : chunks;
import std.encoding : AsciiString;
import std.algorithm : map;

AsciiString ascii(string literal)
{
    return cast(AsciiString) literal;
}

void main()
{
    auto input = ascii("ATGTTTAAA");
    auto codons = input.chunks(3);
    auto aminoacids = codons.map!(
        (codon) {
            if (codon == ascii("ATG"))
                return "M";
            // ...
        }
    );
}
```

Please note that I am using http://dlang.org/phobos/std_encoding.html#.AsciiString here instead of plain string literals. This is to avoid costly UTF-8 decoding which is done for `string` and is never applicable to actual DNA sequence. I remember that making notable performance difference for similar bioinformatics code before.

Comment: Thanks! The section on UTF-8 encoding sounds interesting! Wish there was more documentation on these type of tricks and ideas!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want groups of 3 characters, you can use [std.range.chunks](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_range.html#.chunks).

```
import std.conv : to;
import std.range : chunks;
import std.algorithm : map, equal;

enum seq = "ATGTTTAAA";
auto codons = seq.chunks(3).map!(x => x.to!string);
assert(codons.equal(["ATG", "TTT", "AAA"]));
```

The foreach type of the chunks is `Take!string`, so you may or may not need the `map!(x => x.to!string)`, depending on how you want to use the results.

For example, if you just want to print them:

```
foreach(codon ; "ATGTTTAAA".chunks(3)) { writeln(codon); }
```

Answer (score 0):

```d
import std.algorithm;
import std.regex;
import std.stdio;

int main()
{
  auto seq = "ATGTTTAAA";
  auto rex = regex(r"[AGT]{3}");

  auto codons = matchAll(seq, rex).map!"a[0]";

  writeln(codons);

  return 0;
}
```